# MySQL - count with left join without where performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

Today I found performance issue on the project I'm working. I'm using Laravel framework so most queries are not generated by hand.

The problem:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table LEFT JOIN a ON table.a_id= a.id LEFT JOIN b ON table.b_id = b.id LEFT JOIN c ON table.c_id = c.id
```

where `table` has about 100k records executes `0,7s` whereas

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table
```

executes `0,01s`

So the performance loss is huge. The question is - is it possible to add anything to the query to make query being executed faster (to tell MySQL to ignore LEFT JOINS when there are no WHERE conditions) and the second question - why MySQL uses joins at all in this case when all joins are LEFT and there is no where?

The problem here is that I add many conditions to the query so sometimes many WHERE are used (up to 20-30 conditions) and for some of conditions joins MUST be used.

At the moment I couldn't check indexes (it's quite possible they can cause the problem) but I'm still surprised that MySQL doesn't ignore joins in that case.

As a workaround I'll not use left joins for count in this case when no conditions are used or for about 10-15 conditions where no joins are needed but for others I should create `map` for joins that are needed.

AS @Gordon Linoff mentioned in the answer joins won't create any extra rows, if query without joins generate 10 rows, the exact same of rows will be returned if those joins will be used.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, there is something you can add.  `/*` before `LEFT` and `*/` at the end.  There isn't generally a way to inform the SQL engine that "this is not the query that I really intended to write, run something else."  If you *know* the joins are not needed for the output you want, then remove them from the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I get it, but in my case if I use get from input column=2, I need to use then join and where. At the moment the same query is being generated, first for just getting count of records, and the second to get paginated results. It seems I will need to create map as I mentioned in edit to know that when user will send me condition filter1=2, I then will need to make join with table a, when I get filter2=3, I will need to make join with table b and for filter3=2 I will need to create joins both with table a and b. But first I will verify indexes - maybe they will solve the issue

Comment: It sounds like you are automatically generating code.  If you really want optimal performance you will need to change the `from` clause as well as the `where` clause.  That is, only put in the tables needed for the `where` condition.  Depending on the optimizer probably isn't a good idea.  But thank you for explaining the problem, my previous comment was a bit tongue-in-cheek.

Answer (score 2):

The two queries are not equivalent.  How does MySQL know that there are no *duplicate* values in the two tables, that will result in a multiplication of rows?

There actually is a way.  If the join key is declared to be unique in the second table, then the database engine could know that the join is unnecessary.  I'm pretty sure MySQL does not implement this optimization, but there may be other database engines that do.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is there any way to tell MySql that those joins won't generate any extra rows? I cannot change DB engine even if I wanted

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek: I believe Gordon is correct. MySQL doesn't optimize away the outer joins. As Gordon points out, if the `id` column is not guaranteed to be unique, there's potential for a larger number of rows, when multiple matching rows from `a`, `b` or `c`. MySQL performs the join operations to find out how many rows there actually are, just as if they were inner joins rather than outer joins. (I suspect that `id` column is defined as the PRIMARY (or a UNIQUE) KEY for `a`, `b`, and `c`. The MySQL optimizer just isn't smart enough to optimize away the outer join in this special case.)

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure but couldn't you brought some conditions in where clause to join conditions?

for instance I think the below two queries have not same performance but they are equivalent in case of output:

```
select * 
from A
left join B on A.id=B.ID
where B.field=value
```

and

```
from A
left join B on A.id=B.ID AND B.field=value
```

I think the performance of second one should be much better.